# How can I eliminate normal map seams on cube-mapped Three.js BoxBufferGeometry?

Tags: 3d, three.js

After transforming a `BoxBufferGeometry` into a sphere, and explicitly setting normals correctly as follows:

```js
let geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(1, 1, 1, 64, 64, 64);
const vertices = geometry.attributes.position;
const normals = geometry.attributes.normal;

for (let i = 0; i < vertices.count; i++) {
  const v = new THREE.Vector3().fromArray(vertices.array, i * 3);
  v.normalize();
  normals.setXYZ(i, v.x, v.y, v.z);
  v.setLength(radius);
  vertices.setXYZ(i, v.x, v.y, v.z);
}

vertices.needsUpdate = true;
normals.needsUpdate = true;
```

To test, I'm rendering the sphere with completely flat normal maps (i.e. all pixels are `rgb(128, 128, 255)`) on each face. My assumption is that I should see no difference vs. rendering without a normal map at all, but unfortunately I get significant seams at the edges / uv borders of each face:

[image: Significant normal map seams on sphere]

And here is a fiddle showing the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/Lcf1wgvo/5/

How can I eliminate these seams? I understand that there will be tangent space discontinuities on any sphere, but at the very least, shouldn't a completely flat tangent-space normal map show no seams?

Comment: I guess the problem is that the corresponding uv coordinates are not continuous. You can easily see this with the following fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/4269/. That's because a texture is projected on each side of a box. The uv coordinates of a real sphere look different.

Comment: @Mugen87 Trying the same experiment with a sphere does indeed eliminate seams, but includes deformations at the poles. I suppose that pretty definitively shows that it's due to tangent space issues with the normal map. Presumably there's a way to correct for those issues by adjusting the normal map near seams / poles though?

Comment: I think three.js is generally unable to do what you want, since it creates the tangent frame on the fly using derivatives. It's impossible to render a baked normal map in three.js and has been for a number of versions i believe. You can render something like a brick texture on a flat plane, that should work.

Comment: Yeah, I was digging in a bit here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/9e653203526f6294ef9353383a67f6f8a0567f78/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/normalmap_pars_fragment.glsl and was concerned that may be the case. I *think* it could be solvable by pre-computing the tangents, but I suppose in that case it'll be using custom shaders. Was hoping there'd be a solution in the context of three.js.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168069/discussion-between-pailhead-and-westlangley).

Comment: @clexmond Please try the flat normal map that you can download from http://www.werwackfx.com/index.php/graphictools/graphicsarticles/graphics-articles/45-normalmapsart. With that, I get nearly perfect results with three.js derivative tangents. With an additional small change to the three.js shader, which I can implement, I get perfect results, even with `normalScale` set to ( 100, 100 ).

Comment: @WestLangley That flat normal map seems to be the same as the one I'm importing (different resolution), and you're right that without a large `normalScale` it is barely noticeable. I'm *very* curious what the small change you made to the shader was though?

Comment: `vec3 mapN = texture2D( normalMap, vUv ).xyz * 255./127. - 128./127.;` in `normalmap_pars_fragment.glsl`  Are you able to recompile the library?

Comment: I will absolutely give that a shot, thank you.

Comment: Your normal map appears to be (128, 127, 254 ). The one I linked to is ( 128, 128, 255 );

Comment: I think the biggest error is caused by your map, not the small change to the shader. .. 1/2 day on this... oh well, it is worth it  :)

Comment: Works with no seams with 128,128,255?

Comment: Wow, they actually went away. https://jsfiddle.net/eeoa0ycn/, i get some other weird artifacts where the bump begins but the seams are not there.

Comment: But it fails as soon as this discontinuity is more pronounced. https://jsfiddle.net/65xabvx4/ In theory these seams should not be visible even if you only have 1x1x1 segments on the box.

Comment: @WestLangley You're right, somehow the image I exported offset the green and blue channels by 1?! Although I was still seeing the issue when using a shader to generate a texture of `vec4(0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 0.0)` colored pixels. It seems that your change maybe correcting for those `0.5`s being interpreted as `127`, is that correct?

Comment: It is certainly true that the decoding method in the shader must match the encoding method used to create the normal map. I am not sure of the conventions or standards for encoding a normal map. In any event, I believe the primary problem here was your normal map. Using the 2nd normal map made the most improvement. The change in the constants in the shader make an additional improvement, assuming a proper normal map is used.

Comment: `It is certainly true that the decoding method in the shader must match the encoding method used to create the normal map.` thank you for reiterating this, this is all the point i wanted to make :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use threejs tangent frame and achieve this. You'd have to generate the tangents using the vertex data in order to have them aligned at that seam.

You either need to write your shader (or assemble it) from scratch, or try to use `onBeforeCompile` *(i'd advise against this, it's tempting but may cause more headache than it's worth.)*

If you decide to change the geometry altogether (as advised in the comments) you will experience poor texture distribution.

**edit**

In this particular case, the seam can be avoided by making the sphere very high in resolution. The one from the OP's example creates a 128x64 segment sphere which is pretty high resolution. Unfortunately, this starts to break as the angle between the faces increases. You can see the cube seam, but also the triangle seam (going to the bottom left corner).

The problem is the way three.js generates tangents (on the fly, using `dFdx`, `dFdy`).

[image]

It also quickly fails as you add actual detail to the normal map:
https://jsfiddle.net/65xabvx4/12/

Comment: It seems that, unfortunately, you are correct. I'll likely write a custom shader for this, and in the meantime, I'm using a sphere (which does introduce some stretching).

Comment: Fortunately, you are not correct. If the OP uses a proper normal map, there are no visible seams.

Comment: I think that statement is misleading, what you may want to say (and i was thinking of editing the answer) is: `in this particular case of a cubemapped sphere, if the resolution of the sphere is high enough, the divergence of the tangents will be so small resulting in no seam`. Unfortunately, as soon as you change this to a normal/low res sphere from a high res sphere (32 x 4 = 128 segments) the seams become visible.

Comment: i've edited the answer and added a screenshot @WestLangley

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that ThreeJS (and WebGL) can only support one normal per vertex. So when it creates a `BoxBufferGeometry`, in order to make sharp edges, it duplicates the edge vertices and assigns different normals to each. This can easily be seen when you add a [`VertexNormalsHelper`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/helpers/VertexNormalsHelper) to your fiddle.
[image]
See how the edge vertices have 2 normals and the corners have 3 normals? That means they also have 2 and 3 vertices at each point, one per face.

When you "spherize" the vertex and normals, these points in space still keep their 2 and 3 vertex/normal pairs:

[image]

Red circle (corner vertex) has 3 overlapping normals at that spot, and blue circle (edge vertices) have 2 normals. When rendering, the fragment shader outputs a smooth gradient between connecting vertices, but has a hiccup when blending between two vertices that occupy the same space.

Comment: Why is this a problem? When using triangle soups you have duplicated vertices everywhere. This has nothing to do with normal mapping, the issue is the discontinuity created by computing the TBN frame using derivatives.